# R get the levels associated with the maximum value in a multidimensional contingency table

Tags: r, contingency

With a simple vector like

```
x <- sample(letters[1:3], size=20, replace=T)
```

I would extract the most frequent letter with something like

```
y <- table(x)
print(names(y)[y==max(y)])
"b"
```

However, using the same technique over a multidimensional dataframe does not work:

```
set.seed(5)
x <- data.frame(c1=sample(letters[1:3], size=30, replace=T),
                c2=sample(letters[4:5], size=30, replace=T),
                c3=sample(letters[6:10], size=30, replace=T))
y <- table(x)

print(names(y)[y==max(y)])
NULL
```

How can I extract the levels of c1, c2, and c3 that have the highest value in the contingency table?

I know I could convert the table to a dataframe and find the row where the Freq column is highest, but given the number of dimensions & levels in my dataset, doing the conversion to a dataframe would not fit in my RAM memory.

**Edit:** So my expected output in the second case would be `c, d, j`, as in:

```
z <- data.frame(y)
z[z$Freq==max(z$Freq), 1:3]
   c1 c2 c3
27  c  d  j
```

But note that I cannot use the `data.frame` call on my data due to RAM issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE`:

```
mapply("[", 
       dimnames(y), 
       as.data.frame(which(y == max(y), arr.ind = TRUE)))
# c1  c2  c3 
#"c" "d" "j"

mapply("[", 
       dimnames(y), 
       as.data.frame(which(y == min(y), arr.ind = TRUE)))
#      c1  c2  c3 
# [1,] "a" "d" "f"
# [2,] "b" "d" "g"
# [3,] "c" "d" "g"
# [4,] "b" "e" "g"
# [5,] "a" "d" "h"
# [6,] "b" "d" "h"
# [7,] "c" "d" "h"
# [8,] "c" "e" "h"
# [9,] "a" "e" "i"
#[10,] "b" "e" "i"
#[11,] "c" "e" "i"
```